# Raster images losing quality when clipped?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, data-quality

I'm using the ArcGIS data management clip tool for raster, a jpg file. It is being clipped with a polygon. After the clip is successful, the clipped image is appearing in lower quality and the colors of the pixels are showing up differently, even when they seem to have the same value.

I have tried adjusting all of the raster environment settings to ensure they are the same, what could be causing this?

Comment: A before and after screenshot, as well as details about the clip settings used would be helpful here. Keep in mind a jpg is a compressed file format. When you clip, you're taking that information and modifying it, then writing out a new file. If you write this new file out as a jpg as well, it's being *recompressed*, so there will be some degradation in image quality. It's also possible your layer settings (properties, symbology tab) are altering the appearance - you might make sure a stretch isn't being doubled up as discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104503/

Comment: Thanks, I did not see the question you linked before, I will experiment with those setting at the next opportunity

Comment: Are you having a similar problem to this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210694/rasters-lose-quality-when-georeferencing-using-arcgis-for-desktop There are some steps there that might work for you, but I haven't found a solution to that issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Likely just a differing histogram now the mean, max, min, std dev of the raster may be different once the clip is complete. I doubt your pixels values are changing, just the rendering. Overlay a couple of rasters and click on a few pixels to check using the (i) information button.

Comment: Sorry, reworded the question. The values do appear the same, but the colors are different, I will look into the rendering of them as you suggested, I still don't quite understand why I am losing so much quality

Comment: Try recalculating statistics on your raster.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to choose a export format without data loss. 
this site gives an overview about different types.

You might try LZ77 or LZW compression.

http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000020000000

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple might seem crazy but it work for me.
As working for town planning department we required DP to be clipped and every time it shows very bad quality of image, while I change NoData value (which is actually optional),output image is sufficiently readable with better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I discovered my clipped raster sampling was set to 'nearest neighbor' by default. I went to Layer Properties -> Display -> Resample and changed it to 'Bilinear Interpolation (for continuous data)' and it looks much better now.