# Exporting raster file from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

I am exporting a raster file (tiff) in ArcMap as a png/pdf. But no matter how much I increase the dpi, the exported map looks smoothed version of the original images in my map.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you expand more by what you mean by "exported map looks smoothed version of the original images in my map" or provide a screen capture?

Comment: I have a map in GIS (consisting rasters and shape file). I want to save it as PNG or PDF or anything else. But the exported file looks smoothed out and does not have the same resolution of the map in GIS format.

Comment: Have you adjusted the default dpi and other misc settings (bottom of the Export Map dialog)?  I think the default dpi setting is something like 96.

Comment: yes even if I adjust the dpi to be"3000" it still has the problem. It seems like a low pass filter has been implemented on the image.

Comment: try exporting it to a tiff format first and see if this is not a limitation of your output formats.

Comment: Do you have the latest service pack installed for v10.1?

Comment: I do have the latest version 10.3.

Comment: Exporting as Tiff did the exact same thing by smoothing the image.

Comment: Is there any way to show you the image "GIS map" and "exported map" here? can I attach a file?

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about how the site works. In particular, please try to provide any requested clarifications by using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it rather than creating a comment trail.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of the export, as in is it just for reporting, visualization or would you carry on another analysis work from there? If it is just a matter of exporting high quality image in PDF (if size is not a problem), did you try exporting without any compression? when you export PDF on the advanced tab you can choose not to compress your exported image (default is on LZW)

Comment: Just to import it into the inkscape and beautify that for a scientific paper.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just taking a screen shot.

It seems like ArcGIS is resampling the raster to fit the pdf/png, which makes sense.

You could also physically clip the raster using Extract By Mask (or gdalwarp) then make a map using GIMP or Inkscape equivalent if you don't like how ArcGIS is re-sampling your data.

Comment: Thanks. when I screenshot it is not as high quality as the original map. I'll try the Extract by mask. Thanks. does it mean extracting each raster layer separately and mash them together in InkScape

Comment: I was under the impression that this was one raster. If you extract them using the same polygon and batch it using Python or Model Builder, then you can import them using Inkscape, align them using the alignment tools, then export the page from inkscape. You can also use the clip tool in inkscape to hide the parts you don't want in the page. This is a hackish solution, but it's all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: the problem is I re-grouped the values (reclassified) to be show 100 different colors to just show 4 categories. And then when I export the raster file individually (export by mask) it gives me a raster file equivalent to the original one (good quality) but without regrouping the colors. (100 different colors)

Comment: No, your symbology will not carry over from an extraction. Gimp has tools for changing colors by assignment, but that's a can of worms you don't want to get into. You may want to try this -> http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62199/arcgis-export-raster-keep-color-scheme

Answer (score 0):

If you open the raster property there are some resampling option (nearest neighbor , bilinear, cubic...) in the display tab, you can try some of them to see if that improve the export. Also as said in comment the pdf export window has a format tab where you can set the compression for raster data maybe setting to none could also improve your result.